# preg_replace for URLs adding semicolons after special characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have this expression, to identify URLs and turn them into links:

```
$string = preg_replace("/(\A|[^=\]'\"a-zA-Z0-9])((http|ftp|https|ftps|irc):\/\/[^<>\s()]+)/i", "\\1<a href=\"\\2\">\\2</a>", $string);
```

It works perfectly fine, except when there's punctuation at the end of a URL (like when the URL is at the end of a sentence). It treats the punctuation like it's part of the URL, which obviously means the link won't work.

To fix this, I added a word boundary (\b) at the end of the expression. It works great - periods, commas, etc. no longer get added to the link! EXCEPT for the three characters **&** **'** and **"**. Those not only get combined with the URL, but the replaced string adds a semicolon. For example:

- [aaa].com.
- [bbb].com,
- [ccc].com?
- [xxx].com&
- [yyy].com'
- [zzz].com"

become

- **[aaa].com**.
- **[bbb].com**,
- **[ccc].com**?
- **[xxx].com&**;
- **[yyy].com'**;
- **[zzz].com"**;

(The bold part represents what's now linkified - the semicolon is inserted as plain text.) Periods, commas, and other puctuation are successfully ignored. Ampersands and quote marks are included as part of the link, and a plain text semicolon gets inserted at the end even though it wasn't in the matched text.

I have searched and searched to figure out why, and I can't find anything that explains it. I've tested the expression on preg_replace tester sites, and it *doesn't* cause any problems there - in fact, it works exactly as it should, only matching the URL and not the end character. It's probably something simple that I don't know about regex or preg_replace, but I don't know how to successfully ignore all punctuation/special characters at the end of a URL, and not have some strange insertion of a semicolon after &, ', or ".

Comment: works for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/69euuK no extra semicolon, bet it is else where in your code

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what you're attempting to parse from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a negative lookbehind at the end:

```
/my_url_regex(?<![.!?,'\"])/
```

Comment: Thanks - this was an obvious bit I should've thought about!